# Helm: ignore *~/some/path/to/a/file output* buffers

Tags: helm

In my `*helm for files*` buffer are listed buffers of the form `*~/some/path/to/a/file output*` and I'd like to hide them thanks to `helm-boring-file-regexp-list`. My current attempt with the setting below doesn't work, I guess because of the space in the buffer name.

What am I missing?

```
(setq helm-boring-file-regexp-list '("\\.swf$" "\\.elc$" "\\.pyc$" "\\.aux$"
                                     "\\.idx$" "\\.ind$" "\\.lo*$" "\\.out$"
                                     "\\.toc$" "\\.lof$" "\\.lot$" "\\.acn$"
                                     "\\.acr$" "\\.alg$" "\\.bbl$" "\\.bcf$"
                                     "\\.fls$" "\\.gl*$" "\\.ist$" "\\.xml$"
                                     "\\.slo$" "\\.slg$" "\\.sls$" "\\.xdy$"
                                     "\\.unq$" "\\.mw$" "\\.nav$"
                                     "\\.pyc$" "\\.emacs.d/*"
                                     "\\.gnus.d/*" "\\.gz$"
                                     "\\.log$" "\\ output$" ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't about the space. `helm-boring-file-regexp-list` matches file names. A buffer like `*xxx output` isn't showing the content of a file (in Emacs terminology, it isn't visiting a file), so a file name filter is irrelevant. You need a buffer name filter instead: `helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list`.

```
(defun my-after-load-helm-buffers ()
  (add-to-list 'helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list " output\\*\\'"))
(eval-after 'helm-buffers '(my-after-load-helm-buffers))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but `helm-for-files` still displays the boring `*xxx output*` buffers.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Hmmm. Maybe I'm the one who's missing something. Why does helm for *files* offer the name of a non-file-visiting buffer? I don't really know helm.

Comment: Finally, it looks like it works, but just with `(add-to-list 'helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list " output\\*\\'")`.